# perl cgi passing filehandle

Tags: javascript, perl, upload, cgi

I have perl cgi script and I have form for uploading files.
Everything works fine but I have some control(check my SQL table) after user choose file if file with the same name already exist.
And if exist I print javascript confirm to ask user if he wants to replace old file.
And I dont know how to pass filehandle to script. My code of upload.pl:

```
my $query = new CGI;  
my $file = $query->param("file");
my $confirm = $query->param("confirm"); 
my $name = $query->param("name");

if(!$confirm){
  SQL check
  if(SQL check){
    print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
    print "<form action=\"upload.pl\" method=post name=\"upload.pl\">
       <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"file\" value=\"$file\">
       <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"confirm\" value=\"true\">
       <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"name\" value=\"$name\">
     </form>
     <form action=\"index.pl\" method=GET name=\"index.pl\">
       <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"login\" value=\"$login\">
       <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"token\" value=\"$token\">
     </form>
     <script>
       var answer = confirm(\"WARNING .....\"); 
       if (answer==true){
         document.forms[\"upload.pl\"].submit();
       }
       else{
         document.forms[\"index.pl\"].submit();            
       }
     </script>
     ";
  exit;
  }  
}
```

So after user confirm that he wants to replace file I submit first form and run upload.pl again but when I try

```
my $upload_filehandle = $query->upload("file");
```

it returns nothing.

Is there a way to pass filehandle? 
Or other way without javascript confirmation and submiting script again?

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query->upload("file")
```

is for file-type inputs (e.g. `<input type="file" name="file">`). For other type of inputs, use

```
$query->param("file")
```

If you want to be able to read the value returned by `$query->param("file")` from a file handle, you can use

```
open(my $fh, '<', \$query->param("file"))
```